# MySQL Routine not assigning value to variable?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a table `a` with the following columns:
id
`name`
a_id

where a_id is the id of another `a` row.

Suppose I have 3 rows with the following values:
1, 'name1', null
2, 'name2', 1
3, 'name3', 2

Ok, now I want to create a stored procedure that returns the following string:
"name3|name2|name1"
or, in general, the `name` value of each row that refers to another row until there is no other reference (separated by the | character).

What is wrong with the following code?

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE chain (IN init_name VARCHAR(100), OUT names VARCHAR(1000))
BEGIN
    DECLARE next_id INT default 0;
    DECLARE curr_id INT default 0; /* Just in case */
    DECLARE n VARCHAR(100) default "";

    SET n = init_name;

    SELECT a_id
    INTO next_id
    FROM a
    WHERE `name`=n;


    SET names = n;
    WHILE next_id <> NULL DO
        SET curr_id=next_id; /* Again, just in case */

        SELECT `name`, a_id
        INTO n, next_id
        FROM a
        WHERE id=curr_id;

        SET names = CONCAT(names, "|", n);
    END WHILE;
END$$
```

CALL chain('name3', @names) just outputs "name3"

Comment: I just figured it out.
Sorry guys, newbie mistake.

Instead of the test for next_id <> NULL, you must test for next_id is not null

Answer (score 0):

You need to read @names after calling your procedure :`SELECT @names`. Or if you want procedure to output it, do `SELECT names` in the body of SP (right after `SET names ....`)

Comment: Yes. When I select it, the value of @names is just "name3".

Comment: @ieeehh: Sorry, I didn't read your question carefully, I thought you had a problem returning value from SP... It seems you already figured out the culprit.